# How to display data in firebase using angularfire collection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have some data in firebase in the url "https://wpladv.firebaseio.com/adventure" and I have the following code in my js file:

```
.factory('dataUpdate', ['angularFireCollection', function(angularFireCollection) {
  var dbUrl = 'https://wpladv.firebaseio.com/adventure';
  return {
    adventures: function(){
      var cat = '/adventure';
      return angularFireCollection(dbUrl + cat);
    }
  }
}])
```

I also have the following code in my HTML

```
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="adventure in adventures">
    <div class="well">
      <h4>{{adventure.name}}</h4>
      <h5><em>{{adventure.desc}}</em></h5>
      <p>{{adventure.theme}}</p>
      <p>{{adventure.like}}%</p>
      <p>Taken by {{adventure.used}}</p>
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The data in firebase is in JSON. My question is how do i display the data in the url using angularfire collection object? I am new to angularfire and any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please do this [really simple tutorial](http://angularfire.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted). It'll help you understand the basics of angular and firebase.

You have to bind the firebase data to the target scope.
This is usually done in the controller (see [this specific step](http://angularfire.com/tutorial/#tutorial/basic/3) of the tutorial)